# Observable success method is not firing

Tags: javascript, angular, observable

Can you tell me why this `()` success method is not firing? When I use `forkjoin()` it is working nicely.Success method must fire every time no? Hope it is like a `final` method on `try-catch` block.

**Note:** Please see the inline comments too.

**.ts**

```
 getAllBooksReadAndUnRead(id: number, loader?) {
        this.article.getAllBooksReadAndUnRead(id)
          .map((res: any) => res.json())
          .subscribe(res => {
               this.setAllData(res); //it comes to here
               this.loadingControllerService.dismissLoader(loader);//I have to put this here.Then no problem.But I think it is duplicate of work???
          }, 
          error => {this.loadingControllerService.dismissLoader(loader);},
          () => {this.loadingControllerService.dismissLoader(loader);}//not fire
       });
      }
```

**Api call**

```
 getAllBooksReadAndUnRead(bookId) {
        return this.apiSer.get(`${config.fromThisBook}?page=all&book[]=${bookId}`);
    }
```

**Generic method:**

```
get(api) {
        return new Observable(observer => {
            let header = new Headers();
            this.createHeader(header)
                .then(() => {
                    let options = new BaseRequestOptions();
                    options.withCredentials = true;
                    options.headers = header;
                    this.http.get(api, options)
                        .subscribe(response => {
                            observer.next(response);
                         }, (e) => {
                            observer.error(e);
                        });
                })
        })
    }
```

**post()**

```
post(url, params): Observable<any> {
        return new Observable(observer => {
            let header = new Headers();
            this.createHeader(header)
                .then(() => {
                    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: header });
                    this.http.post(url, params, options)
                        .subscribe(response => {
                            observer.next(response);
                            observer.complete();
                        }, (e) => {
                            observer.error(e);
                        });
                })
        })
    }
```

Comment: does it work at all? the syntax is off. what does `getAllBooksReadAndUnRead` do? can you show its code?

Comment: @Maximus Oh..Can you show me the correct syntax then? See here:https://angular-2-training-book.rangle.io/handout/observables/using_observables.html

Comment: copy from [this plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/kwQQlhM7KWpO9YSC5k00?p=catalogue)

Comment: This `getAllBooksReadAndUnRead` method is working fine.You can see this comment too `this.setAllData(res);//it comes to here`  @Maximus

Comment: Sorry, It was a typo.I have corrected it @Maximus

Comment: show what `getAllBooksReadAndUnRead` method does

Comment: Done.Please see it @Maximus

Comment: I don't any problems, if you add subscribe to the `this.apiSer.get("${config.fromThisBook}?page=all&book[]=${bookId}")` directly does it trigger complete callback?

Comment: You have put me in the right direction.Thanks.Hope you'll see something on my new update too.I would like to hear the issue on the new method (`get(api)`) from you? Please put your answer too @Maximus

Comment: yeah, now it's clear where the problem is, see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45158907/2545680)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you never trigger complete in your custom producer. You need something like this:

```
  get(api) {
    return new Observable(observer => {
      let header = new Headers();
      this.createHeader(header)
        .then(() => {
          let options = new BaseRequestOptions();
          options.withCredentials = true;
          options.headers = header;
          this.http.get(api, options).subscribe(
            response => observer.next(response),
            (e) => observer.error(e),
            () => observer.complete();  <-------------------------
          );
        })
    })
  }
```

Also I think you don't need a custom producer, try like this:

```
  get(api) {
    return Observable.from(this.createHeader()).map((header) => {
      let options = new BaseRequestOptions();
      options.withCredentials = true;
      options.headers = header;
      return this.http.get(api, options);
    }).mergeAll();
  }
```

Here is how it works:

- `Observable.from(this.createHeader())` returns an observable that will deliver values once the promise is resolved
- `.map((header) => {` observes the value that comes from returned promise and makes an HTTP request and returns the result in the form of the observable
- `mergeAll()` - since the previous operation returns and observable, we need to flatten it

Comment: Hehe... Thanks :)

Comment: you're welcome, what does `this.createHeader` do? maybe you don't need your custom producer

Comment: `createHeader(headers: Headers) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            this.storage.get('loggedInUser')
                .then((token: any) => {
                    if (token) headers.append('Authorization', 'token ' + token.token);
                    resolve(headers);
                }, err => {
                    resolve(headers);
                });
        });
    }`

Comment: @Sampath, check my updated answer, try without custom producer

Comment: Can I use the same pattern with the `post()` and `delete()` too?

Comment: yeah, I believe you can.

Comment: Please see my `post()` method above.

Comment: yeah, it's the same pattern

Comment: OK.Thanks a lot for your awesome support :)

Answer (score 0):

I try to avoid wrapping code blocks in parentheses unless I have to, as it makes it easier to confuse their placement. For example, you have an extra closing } in your second to last line that may be causing an issue:

```
getAllBooksReadAndUnRead(id: number, loader?) {
    this.article.getAllBooksReadAndUnRead(id)
      .map((res: any) => res.json())
      .subscribe(res => {
           this.setAllData(res);//it comes to here
      }, 
      error => {this.loadingControllerService.dismissLoader(loader);},
      () => {this.loadingControllerService.dismissLoader(loader);}//not fire
   );
  }
```

I would be inclined to simplify the parentheses like this:

```
  getAllBooksReadAndUnRead(id: number, loader?) {
    this.article.getAllBooksReadAndUnRead(id)
      .map(res: any => res.json())
      .subscribe(res => {
           this.setAllData(res);//it comes to here
      }, 
      error => this.loadingControllerService.dismissLoader(loader),
      () => this.loadingControllerService.dismissLoader(loader)//not fire
   )};
```

Comment: Nope.I have used parentheses there hence I have to put more clearing code on those methods.For clarity, I have removed on above sample.

Comment: There's still an extra } on your second to last line. Compare my top example above that maintains your additional parentheses to your original. I understand if you need to add code you require the additional parentheses, that makes sense, I just don't add them until I'm adding the additional lines as it makes the code easier to read without.

Comment: I'm using `VS code` and all the `angular` plugins which it requires to identify those issues.So I can't see any errors on my code base and the app is working fine.